# Aim of Factory pattern is to stop us from over-riding or re-writing the functions which instantiate?

Tags: factory-method, factory

http://www.cs.unc.edu/~stotts/GOF/hires/pat3cfso.htm

`CreateMaze` is the function which instantiates the objects. IMO, according to factory pattern we are not supposed to overload or modify or re-write the function which instantiates objects.

But in the example, the CreateMaze function returns a Maze*. So, now if we have to write an EnchangedMaze class, will we have to re-write CreateMaze function to return a pointer of EnchantedMaze?

From: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~stotts/GOF/hires/chap3fso.htm

> Changing the layout means changing this member function, either by overriding it—which means reimplementing the whole thing—or by changing parts of it—which is error-prone and doesn't promote reuse.

Isn't this what factory pattern wants to avoid?

What point am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood the purpose of the pattern.

The point of a pattern is never that you're not supposed to change anything ever again. You're the author of the system, when the requirements change (and they *will* change), you will *have* to change the corresponding parts. No class is safe from that.

The specific point of the factory pattern is that a client program (possibly written by someone else) doesn't *have* to know the specific type that the factory returns, but only the interface that it was written to. That way, when the factory owner changes the `Car` implementation from `GasGuzzlerCar` to `ElegantElectricCar`, the client program does not have to be rewritten because it only uses the type `Car`.

The alternative would be for the vendor to export the type `GasGuzzlingCar` and then breaking all clients whenever that type changes. That is clearly the inferior solution. So you see, the purpose of the factory is *to insulate clients of a library against changes within the library*, particularly changes that could leak outside the library via type declarations.

Comment: Thanks, this means that createMaze function which instantiates the maze will be rewritten with every new type of maze?

Comment: Without factory being abstract, client depends on a concrete factory implementation and will always receive a given return value in same circumstances. This in fact couples client to created object.

Answer (score -2):

"Factory" indeed introduces a method that is not supposed to be modified or overridden. 
"Factory Method" on the other hand is a completely different pattern, a special case of "Abstract Factory".
The only thing that is common between "Factory" and "Abstract Factory" is they are both  creational patterns.

There is no contradiction in linked article as it does not  describe "Factory".